# FancyBox onload show is not working with normal click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox

I'm creating a little JavaScript game. When the page loads, it is supposed to display a Fancybox over the page.

Here is my jQuery for the Fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#test').fancybox({ 
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic', 
'showCloseButton' : false,
'overlayOpacity' : 1
}).click();
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<a id="test" href="#test2" style="display:none;">Test the Popup</a>
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="test2"  style='padding:10px; background:#fff;width:550px;'>
<b style="color:#FF9C21;font-size:24px;">HTML Jeoprady</b><br>
<span style="font-size:15px;">
You think your good at HTML? Well test your skill here.<br>
Please know there is more to HTML than 2 tags ;)<br>
Are you ready?<br><br>
<b style="color:#FF9C21;font-size:24px;">Name:</b>
<input type="text" id="team1" />
</span>
<br><br>
<span id="start" onclick="loop();" style="cursor:pointer;color:#FF9C21;font-size:20px;"> 

<center>Start Game!</center></span>
</div>
</div>
```

All of my FancyBoxes that activate onclick show, but then it automatically closes about 5 seconds after it opens.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Pls update your post to show the element html being clicked. Ala, A HREF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did a manual call you could do:

```
var theContent = $('#div-id').html();

$.fancybox(theContent, {
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic', 
'showCloseButton' : false,
'overlayOpacity' : 1
});
```

And then, the contents of `#div-id` would be in the manual call.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of .click() you should probably just use .open()

Edit: Silly me, there is no .open(). I have had issues with firing click programmatic click events before. If the method you are trying is causing issues, try this

```
$('#test').trigger('click')
```

or alternatively use a manual call

```
$.fancybox('html content here',{options})
```

Comment: yup, sorry I was confused. I updated my post - there is a way of calling fancybox in a static fashion instead of on a jquery reference

Comment: I tryed using trigger but it didnt work. and I dont like using the manual call.